# My ArI was using a potentiometer and the system shorted maybe. Do I have to replace the USB interface chip? It doesn't reset also

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

See I was using a micro analog rotary potentiometer to control a servo. The pot was in a pcb. The 5v output and gnd were connected to arduino from the pot. The third pin and 5v got touched and it got fused. The Rx and TX led glowed constantly till I disconnected the 12v input. [image: this is the constant state of my arduino even if I press reset]

Comment: 12V input + short on 5V = possible dead 5V regulator (if it didn't go into thermal shutdown). Possible dead 5V regulator = unknown voltage on 5V rail (could be as high as 12V). High voltage on 5V rail = dead Arduino.

Comment: What to do now? Buy a new one?

Comment: Unless you like diagnosing hardware faults and doing surface mount soldering then that's the easiest option. If the PC can still see the board the USB chip is OK. The main MCU may be dead though.